# Is there a list of Ethereum Dapps that have confirmed moving over to EOS?

Tags: dapp, ethereum

People say Ethereum dapps are moving to EOS platform. But where is this list of Dapps? And which ones are the most active that is actually moving to EOS?

Answer (score 0):

> But where is this list of Dapps?

There are various aggregators of active dApps on EOSIO:

- [DappRadar](https://dappradar.com/eos-dapps), a website that also has a section for Ethereum dapps
- [EOSIndex](https://eosindex.io/)
- [EOSProjects](https://eosprojects.org/)

> Is there a list of Ethereum Dapps that have confirmed moving over to EOS?

I'm not aware of any resource that tracks dApps based on what platform they're moving from. There have been [discussions](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/9620rd/list_of_projects_moving_to_eos/) in public forums and various [comparisons](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/9620rd/list_of_projects_moving_to_eos/), but nothing particularly organised to my knowledge.